# JavaScript smooth page scroll like at goldensuisse.com

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

I've been googling & googling. I've found out a locomotive-scroll, but it does not work for my Nuxt.JS (Vue.JS) project.

I want to achieve the smooth and max speed limited scroll effect like at goldensuisse.com, do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: that site you referenced is using nuxt in combination with https://idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar/

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna try it out. How did you find out? Did you look at the page's html cide?

Comment: If you inspect the page the top level div has the id __nuxt.

If you inspect the scollbar (it's a custom element) then it has the classes 'scrollbar-track scrollbar-track-y'. if you google those classes then it links to that plugin.

Comment: I've must have been over see this, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** "that site you referenced is using nuxt in combination with idiotwu.github.io/smooth-scrollbar" - dantheman

thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/13929140/dantheman!